# JTree update after add or delete file in system

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I've got a JTree to display and transfer directories and files on C disk. In this JTree the user can change the location of file by drag&drop. I've implemented the class TransferHandler to handle the transfer of DefaultMutableTreeNode and in the same time to transfer file from one location to other. From the first time I drag and drop file it's ok (the defaultMutableTreeNode of this file is removed and is created new defaultMutableTreeNode and this file is also transfer on disk). But the problem is when I do this the second time. The JTree doesn't update after changes and I can't drag&drop defaultMutableTreeNode.

I call all possible updates function for e.g. updateUI and they doesn't work. I spend three days on it and I have no idea how to do it.
I paste two functions from the class extends TransferHandler. I think the jtree should be update in one of this function. Could anyone take a look on it and tell me when update this tree and how?

```
//bundle up selected files into one list and export it
protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
   DefaultMutableTreeNode tmpNode;
   JTree node = (JTree)c;
   TreePath[] treePaths = node.getSelectionPaths();
   if(treePaths != null) {
      ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodesToCopy = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
      fileToCopy = new ArrayList<File>();
      ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodesToRemove = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
      fileToRemove = new ArrayList<File>();
      DefaultMutableTreeNode topNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)treePaths[0].getLastPathComponent();
    //  File dir = (File)topNode.getUserObject();
      for(int i=0; i<treePaths.length; i++) {
          DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = 
                  (DefaultMutableTreeNode)treePaths[i].getLastPathComponent();
          File file = (File)currentNode.getUserObject();
          if(currentNode.getLevel() < topNode.getLevel()) 
              break;
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
              tmpNode = FileNodeTree.createNodes(null,file);
              nodesToCopy.add(tmpNode);
              fileToCopy.add(file);
              fileToRemove.add(file);
              nodesToRemove.add(currentNode);
          } else {    
              nodesToCopy.add(copyToNode(file));
              fileToCopy.add(file);
              nodesToRemove.add(currentNode);
              fileToRemove.add(file);
          }
      }
      DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = nodesToCopy.toArray(
              new DefaultMutableTreeNode[nodesToCopy.size()]);
      removeNodes = nodesToRemove.toArray(
              new DefaultMutableTreeNode[nodesToRemove.size()]);
      return new FilesTransferable(nodes);
   }
   return null;
}

private DefaultMutableTreeNode copyToNode(File node) {
    return new DefaultMutableTreeNode(node);
}


public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
   DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = null;
   if(!canImport(support))
       return false;

   try {
      nodes = (DefaultMutableTreeNode[]) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(fileFlavor);
      for(DefaultMutableTreeNode nodess : nodes)
          System.out.println("nodess: "+nodess);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e1) {
       System.err.println("UnsupportedFlavorException: "+e1.getMessage());
   }

   //fetch the drop location, path & childIndex
   JTree.DropLocation dropLoc = (JTree.DropLocation)support.getDropLocation();
   TreePath path = dropLoc.getPath();

   int childIndex = dropLoc.getChildIndex();

   //create new nodes and insert it into JTree
   DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
   File top = (File)parent.getUserObject();
   JTree tree = (JTree)support.getComponent();

   DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
   //configure for dropMode
   int index = childIndex;   //for dropMode.INSERT
   if(childIndex == -1)     //for dropMode.ON
       index = parent.getChildCount();
  //insert data into JTree
   for(int i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) 
       model.insertNodeInto(nodes[i], parent, index++);
   try {
        for(File file : fileToCopy) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(file, new File(top+"/"+file.getName()));

            } else {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), 
                    (new File(top+"/"+file.getName()).toPath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }
   } catch (IOException e) {
           System.err.println("Cannot copy to other directory " + e.getMessage());
           }
   return true;
```

Comment: Do you have any exception? Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: When I drag&drop defaultMutableTreeNode the second time, I've got IOException from function importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport) and it's: "Cannot copy to other directory C:\Users\Zanette\Pictures\folder". It seems like JTree doesn't know new location of MutableTreeNode and I cannot drag it again.